# How to call the base F# method from a computation expression in an overridden method?

Tags: f#

How to call the base F# method from a computation expression in an overridden method?

Here is some contrived example of the surprising problem. Do not ask why I need
this particular scenario, the actual use case makes more sense but it is
difficult to represent. In particular, `async` is irrelevant, in the actual
case I use a different computation expression and do not even need the bang
(`!`) for calling the base method. But the symptoms are the same.

```ml
// Base class with a virtual method
type T1 () =
    abstract Test : unit -> Async<unit>
    default _.Test () =
        async {
            printfn "In test"
        }

// Derived class with an overridden method calling the base in a computation expression
type T2 () =
    inherit T1 ()
    override _.Test () =
        async {
            do! base.Test ()
        }

let t2 = T2 ()
t2.Test () |> Async.RunSynchronously
```

The above code cannot compile:

```
error FS0405: A protected member is called or 'base' is being used. This is
only allowed in the direct implementation of members since they could
escape their object scope.
```

What does this cryptic message mean? I am calling a public member from the
direct implementation of it, like the compiler "wants".

The main question then, how do I call the base method in such cases? What is
the idiomatic F# way?

The workarounds are possible, for example:

```ml
type T1 () =
    abstract Test : unit -> Async<unit>
    default m.Test () =
        m.DoTest ()

    member _.DoTest () =
        async {
            printfn "In test"
        }

type T2 () =
    inherit T1 ()
    override m.Test () =
        async {
            do! m.DoTest ()
        }

let t2 = T2 ()
t2.Test () |> Async.RunSynchronously
```

I am not really looking for workarounds but it would be interesting to see others.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem here is that code inside `async` is compiled into a separate class, which then lives outside of the current class and so it cannot call the base methods in a typical way.

In this case, you can call the method before the `async` block. This works, because this is just a part of the normal method body. The method returns `async` which is not actually executed until you call it with `do!`

```
type T2 () =
    inherit T1 ()
    override __.Test () =
        let baseTest = base.Test ()
        async {
            do! baseTest
        }
```

This is a nice but limited trick. It will not work when you need to first compute some parameters and then pass them to `Test` (because you cannot make `baseTest` a function - it has to be a value). The only option in that case is to define a helper method that calls the base method:

```
type T2 () =
    inherit T1 ()
    member private x.BaseTest() = 
        base.Test ()
    override x.Test () =
        async {
            do! x.BaseTest()
        }
```

I think this is a bit nicer than your workaround, because it does not require any virtual methods in the base class. `base.Test` call will work from a private method of the derived class.

Comment: Thank you for the details and the hint. Your workaround is often better, in particular it does not require the base class tweaks, not always possible. My workaround is "better" for many derived classes with the same issue. I will mark it as an answer after a while, I doubt there is a better way...

Comment: Accepted, thank you once again. So... I understand "why" but is it "OK" that F# is designed this way?

Comment: I think it's not great, but I'm not sure there is a way to make it work. It's just one of those unfortuante interactions between OOP and F#. Mainly, I don't think making this work is such a high priority - I think most people who use OOP with F# use interfaces rather than implementation inheritance, so this is a relatively rare issue.

Comment: This is a helpful workaround, but It makes me wonder how it’s legal to call a private member within a computation expression. Seems like it should cause the same sort of problem that `base` does in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

The workaround is to use a self-identifier:

```ml
type T2 () as self =
    inherit T1 ()
    override _.Test () =
        async {
            do! self.Test ()
        }
```

I think the reason that `base` is not allowed here is that in creating the `T1`, it would need to know about the `T1`. So the `T1` becomes recursively defined, and F# doesn't favour recursive definitions by default. `as self` makes `T2` recursively defined and allows this.

Comment: I think it results in stack overflow. `self.Test` just calls the same, not base method.

Comment: Ok sorry I didn't get the problem originally then. I doubt you can get access to the default methods if you override it.

Comment: No problem to call `base.Test` from `Test` outside the computation expression.