# Custom Identity Usermanager from C# to F#

Tags: f#, asp.net-core-identity

We currently have the following code

```
public class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationUserManager(IUserStore<ApplicationUser> store, IOptions<IdentityOptions> optionsAccessor, IPasswordHasher<ApplicationUser> passwordHasher, IEnumerable<IUserValidator<ApplicationUser>> userValidators, IEnumerable<IPasswordValidator<ApplicationUser>> passwordValidators, ILookupNormalizer keyNormalizer, IdentityErrorDescriber errors, IServiceProvider services, ILogger<UserManager<ApplicationUser>> logger) : base(store, optionsAccessor, passwordHasher, userValidators, passwordValidators, keyNormalizer, errors, services, logger)
    {
    }

    public override async Task<IdentityResult> ResetPasswordAsync(ApplicationUser user, string token, string newPassword)
    {
        var result = await base.ResetPasswordAsync(user, token, newPassword);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            user.ChangePasswordDate = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1);
            user.ChangePassword = false;
            await base.UpdateAsync(user);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

How would i convert this to f#?

Any help would be appreciated

Greetings,

Glenn

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using F# 6, you can use the new [task builder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/whats-new/fsharp-6#task-), like this:

```ml
open Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity

type ApplicationUserManager(store, optionsAccessor, passwordHasher, userValidators, passwordValidators, keyNormalizer, errors, services, logger) =
    inherit UserManager<ApplicationUser>(store, optionsAccessor, passwordHasher, userValidators, passwordValidators, keyNormalizer, errors, services, logger)

    member private _.BaseResetPasswordAsync(user, token, newPassword) =
        base.ResetPasswordAsync(user, token, newPassword)

    override this.ResetPasswordAsync(user, token, newPassword) =
        task {
            let! result = this.BaseResetPasswordAsync(user, token, newPassword)
            if result.Succeeded then
                user.ChangePasswordDate <- DateTime.Now.AddYears(1)
                user.ChangePassword <- false
                let! _result = this.UpdateAsync(user)
                ignore _result
            return result;
        }
```

The private `Base` method is required because [you can't refer directly to `base` within a computation expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59911206/how-to-call-the-base-f-method-from-a-computation-expression-in-an-overridden-me).

Note that you're ignoring the result of `UpdateAsync` in your C# code. I've done the same thing here, but I don't know if it's wise.